# datagridview cell edit and save functionality in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on datagridview in c# windows forms application and I'm loading the data from the database, now i want the user to be able to able to edit the cell value and save the value to the database, how to edit the cell value and how can i save the value to the database?

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=sa;password=123;database=employee");
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from UserReg", con);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds, "p");
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["p"];
```

Comment: Note that "how to handle a `DataGridView` cell being edited" and "how to save the value to the database" are two separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the way to update a database with `DataGridView` is using of DataGridView's events:

```
DataGridView.CellBeginEdit

DataGridView.CellValidating

DataGridView.CellEndEdit
```

Let say: `private DataGridView dgv;`
Add handlers of events

```
dgv.CellBeginEdit += dgv_CellBeginEdit;
dgv.CellValidating += dgv_CellValidating;
dgv.CellEndEdit += dgv_CellEndEdit;

private void dgv_CellBeginEdit(Object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
     //Here we save a current value of cell to some variable, that later we can compare with a new value
    //For example using of dgv.Tag property
    if(e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        this.dgv.Tag = this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value;
        //Or cast sender to DataGridView variable-> than this handler can be used in another datagridview
    }
}

private void dgv_CellValidating(Object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    //Here you can add all kind of checks for new value
    //For exapmle simple compare with old value and check for be more than 0
    if(this.dgv.Tag = this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value)
        e.Cancel = true;    //Cancel changes of current cell
    //For example used Integer check
    int32 iTemp;
    if (Int32.TryParse(this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value, iTemp) = True && iTemp > 0)
    {
        //value is ok
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = True;
    }
}

Private Sub dgvtest1_CellEndEdit(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Because CellEndEdit event occurs after CellValidating event(if not cancelled)
    //Here you can update new value to database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                //after you've filled your ds, on event above try something like this
                try
                {

                    da.Update(ds);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used OleDb but you can use SQL. Here is the code I usually use for the same.

```
OleDbCommand sCommand;
    OleDbDataAdapter sAdapter;
    OleDbCommandBuilder sBuilder;
    OleDbConnection connection;
    DataSet sDs;
    DataTable sTable;
    string myMode = "";
    private void BtnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        sCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
        sAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sCommand);
        sBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
        sDs = new DataSet();
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Table");
        sTable = sDs.Tables["Table"];
        connection.Close();
        DataGrid.DataSource = sTable;
        DataGrid.ReadOnly = true;
        DataGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }
    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid.ReadOnly = false;
        myMode = "add";
    }
    private void BtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid.ReadOnly = false;
        myMode = "edit";
    }
    private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myMode = "";
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete",      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DataGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            sAdapter.Update(sTable);
        }
    }
    private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myMode == "add")
        {
            sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            MessageBox.Show("Prices Are Successfully Added.", "Saved.", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else if (myMode == "edit")
        {
            string query = "UPDATE Table_Name SET " +
                "Column1 = '" + DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
                "Column2 = " + DataGrid.SelecteddRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + ", " +
                "WHERE CONDITION";
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            sCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            sAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sCommand);
            sBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sDs = new DataSet();
            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Table");
            sTable = sDs.Tables["Table"];
            connection.Close();
            DataGrid.DataSource = sTable;
            DataGrid.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`DataGridView` Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx) list.  You need to subscribe to the appropriate event, and handle it accordingly.  Namely, you're interested in [`DataGridView.CellValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx).

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += ValueChangedHandler;

private void ValueChangedHandler(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    // do what is appropriate here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to enable editing on datagridview

```
dtg.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
```

Then use below event

```
private void dtg_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            dtg.ReadOnly = false;
        }
}
```

The above two events will enable editing in datagridview.

Then use below event to save the updated data back to db.

```
private void dtg_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
}
```