# DataGridView editing

Tags: c#, datagridview, edit

I have a windows form project C#

I added a DataGridView and added a binding to the data set as well as checked boxes to 
add
edit 
delete

now i can edit the cells but how do you save after editing ?

Comment: I cannot help you as I am not a C# person,but I would advice you to add more details and if possible part of your tried code,so that the members can understand and help you quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    protected void myGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string id=// To find key of current row. e.g: myGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string text=//To find the text value from the current row.
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(" your query");
            UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
GridView1.EditIndex = -1; //After updating, please set EditIndex and re-bind the GridView.
            BindGridView();
    }
```

You can check the complete functions from the below link:

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/GridView_Insert_Edit_Update_Delete.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
dgv.CellBeginEdit += dgv_CellBeginEdit;
dgv.CellValidating += dgv_CellValidating;
dgv.CellEndEdit += dgv_CellEndEdit;

private void dgv_CellBeginEdit(Object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
     //Here we save a current value of cell to some variable, that later we can compare with a new value
    //For example using of dgv.Tag property
    if(e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        this.dgv.Tag = this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value;
        //Or cast sender to DataGridView variable-> than this handler can be used in another datagridview
    }
}

private void dgv_CellValidating(Object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    //Here you can add all kind of checks for new value
    //For exapmle simple compare with old value and check for be more than 0
    if(this.dgv.Tag = this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value)
        e.Cancel = true;    //Cancel changes of current cell
    //For example used Integer check
    int32 iTemp;
    if (Int32.TryParse(this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value, iTemp) = True && iTemp > 0)
    {
        //value is ok
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = True;
    }
}

Private Sub dgvtest1_CellEndEdit(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Because CellEndEdit event occurs after CellValidating event(if not cancelled)
    //Here you can update new value to database
}
```

[datagridview cell edit and save functionality in windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424768/datagridview-cell-edit-and-save-functionality-in-windows-forms)

check above post for more details.