# Update database from selected datagridview selected value C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am wondering what is the easier way to do update statement for updating my `database` from `datagridview` selected row.

I mean, I have filled my `datagridview` with `database` values. Now, I want to update values from `selected cell`.

My code is:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(sb.ToString());
conn.Open();
OracleDataAdapter sd = new OracleDataAdapter("select First_Name,Last_Name,Group,Date from Person", conn);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
sd.Fill(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
conn.Close();
```

Filling `datagridview` works fine, but now I want to double click on `selected cell`, type new value, click enter and have this value changed. Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you try making your `datagridview` editable?

Comment: RowUpdated event?

Comment: Write an Update Statement with Variable Id. Then listen to RowUpdated event and call the Update Statement if the row is updated with new value. Nicer way would be to use EntityFramework maybe but it's some work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datagridview cell edit and save functionality in windows forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424768/datagridview-cell-edit-and-save-functionality-in-windows-forms)